# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')

Tags: discord.js

So I was updating my bot to discord.js v13 and apparently my logging system has now broke, for some reason it can't read the ID of the guild where this log is occurring.

**banAdd.js**

```js
const { MessageEmbed} = require("discord.js");
const {red_light} = require("../../other/colors.json");
const Channel = require('../../models/ModerationModel.js');

module.exports = async (bot, guild, user) => {
    const guildDB = await Channel.findOne({
       guildId: guild.id
     }, async (err, guild) => {
       if(err) console.error(err)

       if (!guild) {
         const newGuild = new Channel({
           guildId: guild.id,
           modChannel: null,
           msgChannel: null
         });
         await newGuild.save().then(result => console.log(result)).catch(err => console.error(err)); 
       }
     });   

    const modChannel = guild.channels.cache.get(guildDB.modChannel); 

  if (!modChannel) {
    return console.log(`No message channel found`);
  }
  let mEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor(`Member Unbanned`, user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic : true}))
  .setColor(red_light)
  .setDescription(`${user} ${user.tag}`)
  .setThumbnail(`${user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic : true})}`)
  .setFooter(`ID: ${user.id}`)
  .setTimestamp()
  modChannel.send({embeds:[mEmbed]});
}
```

**Error**

```js
/home/runner/switch-beta-test/events/guild/banRemove.js:13
           guildId: guild.id,
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')
    at /home/runner/switch-beta-test/events/guild/banRemove.js:13:27
    at /home/runner/switch-beta-test/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:5074:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

I have no idea why this is not working as it works in previous versions but updating to discord.js V13 completely broke this system. I tried looking at any possible solution but I can't find a single solution.

Comment: How do you call this function? When passing in `guild` is it really what you think? Is it maybe in a DM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this error was because `guild` can no longer be defined during a users ban or unban, `guild` and `user` should be replaced with `ban` in both the unban and ban logs.

**CODE**

```js
const { MessageEmbed} = require("discord.js");
const {red_light} = require("../../other/colors.json");
const Channel = require('../../models/ModerationModel.js');

module.exports = async (bot, ban) => {
    const guildDB = await Channel.findOne({
       guildId: ban.guild.id
     }, async (err, guild) => {
       if(err) console.error(err)

       if (!guild) {
         const newGuild = new Channel({
           guildId: ban.guild.id,
           modChannel: null,
           msgChannel: null
         });
         await newGuild.save().then(result => console.log(result)).catch(err => console.error(err)); 
       }
     });   

    const modChannel = ban.guild.channels.cache.get(guildDB.modChannel); 

  if (!modChannel) {
    return console.log(`No message channel found`);
  }
  let mEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor(`Member Unbanned`, ban.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic : true}))
  .setColor(red_light)
  .setDescription(`${ban.user} ${ban.user.tag}`)
  .setThumbnail(`${ban.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic : true})}`)
  .setFooter(`ID: ${ban.user.id}`)
  .setTimestamp()
  modChannel.send({embeds:[mEmbed]});
}
```

After this the error should no longer show.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the `guild` variable is empty doesn't have a value `null` and when you do `guild.id` you're trying to access a property that don't exist

Make sure that the `guild` variable is assigned to a value

Probably they add some changes to the new version of npm package go check the docs

Comment: In my mongoDB cluster the guildID is already set since it was set before I updated to discord.js V13, the error is coming from it entirely trying to create new data for already existing data, I don't know what broke this system as it worked fine before updating my bot.

Comment: Probably they add some changes to the new version  of npm package go check the docs